# Totals Row for Tab with Table Custom Data

Tags: custom-fields

I have some custom data in a "tab with tables" style.  One of the fields is an integer type.  I'd like to add a summary at the bottom of the table with totals for this field.  Is that possible to do? Any pointers to what hook to use or how I can build it?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd do it by adding some javascript code to the page, and just use jQuery to add the totals row.

A super-quick way to do this would be to place the code inside `{literal}<script>` tags in a `.tpl.extra` file.